# Increasing maxContentLength and maxBodyLength in Axios

Tags: javascript, node.js, ajax, axios

I am using "Axios" to call a WCF method that takes as parameter file information and content.
The file is read and sent as a base64 encoded string.
My issue is that when the file size exceeds a certain limit, AXIOS throws an exception: "Error: Request body larger than maxBodyLength limit".
I looked up the issue and found that all solutions suggest increasing the maxContentLength / maxBodyLength parameters in the AXIOS configuration object, but did not succeed.
Find Below an implemented test case in node.js:

```
    var axios = require('axios');
    var fs = require('fs');
    var path = require('path')
    var util = require('util')
    let readfile = util.promisify(fs.readFile)

    async function sendData(url,data) {
        let params = data
    
        let resp = await axios({
            method: 'post',
            url: url,
            data: JSON.stringify(params),
            headers: { 'Accept': 'application/json', 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }
            // maxContentLength: 100000000,
            // maxBodyLength: 1000000000
        }).catch(err => {
            throw err;
        })
        return resp;
      }
    async function ReadFile(filepath) {
        try{
            
            let res = await readfile(filepath,'base64')
            let filename = path.basename(filepath).split('.').slice(0, -1).join('.')
            let ext = path.extname(filepath)
            
            return {data:res,fext:ext,fname:filename}
            let x = 1
        }
        catch(err)
        {
            throw err
        }
    
    }
    (async () => {
        try {
    
            let img = await ReadFile('Files/1.pdf')
            let res = await sendData('http://183.183.183.242/EMREngineEA/EMRWS.svc/web/EMR_TestUploadImg',img)
            console.log(res)
    
        }
        catch (ex) {
            console.log(ex)
        }
    }
    )();
```

In my case, the pdf file is 20 MB, upon running, an error is thrown.
"Error: Request body larger than maxBodyLength limit"

I tried to setting the   maxContentLength: 100000000, maxBodyLength: 1000000000
as presented above, but did not succeed.

Your help is appreciated.

Comment: can you try setting it to `Infinity` ?

Comment: Yes, it throws another error: Error: Request failed with status code 404

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The maxBodyLength seems to work for me in this simple test, I upload data to a local Express server. If I try to upload more than the maxBodyLength I get the same error you're getting. So I suspect there's something more, like a redirect happening in your case that's triggering the error.

There is an issue logged for axios [here](https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/1362) that seems to reference the problem, it suggests setting maxContentLength to Infinity (as the other commenter suggests).

e.g.

```
maxContentLength: Infinity,
maxBodyLength: Infinity
```

Test code below:

```
const axios = require("axios");

function generateRandomData(size) {
    const a = Array.from({length: size}, (v, k) => Math.floor(Math.random()*100)); 
    return { data: a, id: 1 };
}

async function uploadData(url, size) {
    let params = generateRandomData(size);
    let stringData = JSON.stringify(params);
    console.log(`uploadData: Uploading ${stringData.length} byte(s)..`);
    let resp = await axios({
        method: 'post',
        url: url,
        data: stringData,
        headers: { 'Accept': 'application/json', 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
        maxContentLength: 100000000,
        maxBodyLength: 1000000000
    }).catch(err => {
        throw err;
    })
    console.log("uploadData: response:", resp.data);
    return resp;
}

uploadData("http://localhost:8080/upload", 10000000);
```

Corresponding server code:

```
const express = require("express");
const port = 8080;
const app = express();
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')

app.use(bodyParser.json({limit: '50mb'}));

app.post('/upload', (req, res, next) => {
    console.log("/upload: Received data: body length: ", req.headers['content-length']);
    res.json( { status: 'ok', bytesReceived: req.headers['content-length']});
})

app.listen(port);
console.log(`Serving at http://localhost:${port}`);
```

Comment: You were right, the issue was with IIS configuration: IIS-->Request filtering-->Maximum allowed content length

Comment: Excellent, glad to hear you found the issue!

Comment: Can it expose the system to Oversize Payload Attacks by having the maxContentLength and maxBodyLength set to infinity?

Comment: This is setting properties on the client side, so it shouldn't expose the system to these types of attacks.