# Don't want to abort HTTP request until response didn't come from backend

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I am working on React web application with a Node backend in which I have implemented the functionality to upload an Excel sheet. If the Excel sheet contains fewer records then it is uploaded successfully. But if there are more than 4,000 records then HTTP request terminates but process in backend goes on. I don't want to abort the request until the response comes from the backend.

I have tried AbortController, axios. But not working for me.

front end api call
[image]

code:
 const data = new FormData();
            data.set("supplier_id", parseInt(this.state.productInfoFormData.productInfoSupplierId));
            data.set("supplier_name", this.state.productInfoFormData.productInfoSupplierName);
            data.append(
                "upload_xlsx",
                this.state.isNew == true
                    ? this.state.productInfoFormData.productInfoAttachment
                    : ""
            );

axios({
                    method:'POST',
                    url: 'http://localhost:9001/addProductInfo',
                    timeout:1000*300,
                    data,
                    headers: {
                        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                    }
                  })
                  .then((response) => {
                    console.log(response);
                  }, (error) => {
                    console.log(error);
                  });

Comment: I think the size is the problem, check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58655532/increasing-maxcontentlength-and-maxbodylength-in-axios

Comment: what is the error you are getting?

Comment: I think the issue is about your backend. Please include more details (eg: code or network data or smth else)

Comment: Also note that requests taking more than 30 seconds tend to be aborted automatically (browser, firewall, load balancer etc).


If uploading actually works, I'd strongly suggest uploading the file, returning a [status 202](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/202) immediately with a URL that the client can ping to get status info.

Comment: @chandan_kr_jhano error just the api failed...

Comment: @MisirJafarov modified the code

Comment: @Christian i have extended the timeout but browser is aborting the request after 2 mins

Comment: @PriyankaGupta the issue is not about client side (browser). I think your backup aborts requests if it takes longer times. Check extending timeout limit for your backend (also check reverse proxies too - nginx, apache)

Comment: @MisirJafarov Thank you for your answer. Your solution works for me. Thank you so much.

Comment: Oops. i made a small mistake. Instead of "backend" i write "backup".

Comment: @MisirJafarov No worries. But i got your point.