# Download more than 80MB of data using Axios

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, csv, xlsx

Is there any functionality or module available to Get 80MB of JSON object data?

The obtained JSON object will be made available to download as csv/xls.

Currently I am using `axios.get("/users/100000");` . this is breaking the code.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Increasing maxContentLength and maxBodyLength in Axios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58655532/increasing-maxcontentlength-and-maxbodylength-in-axios)

Answer (score 1):

You can increase the limit in Axios;

```
let resp = await axios({
        method: 'get',
        url: url,
        maxContentLength: 100000000,
        maxBodyLength: 1000000000
})
```