# Errors When Sending Form Data with XHR

Tags: javascript, node.js, azure-functions, xmlhttprequest, file-transfer

I'm needing to transmit files from one cloud service to another using Azure Functions running Node. I've installed the necessary packages (axios, form-data, xmlhttprequest) and developing using VSCode.

Often times these files will be slightly larger than 10MB, so Axios is not an option - I've tried setting Content-Length = Infinity but that still would not work for me (as seen in [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58655532/increasing-maxcontentlength-and-maxbodylength-in-axios) S.O. post). As long as the file is less than 10MB Axios works fine and my code works... but, I need to account for these random larger files.

I'm now trying to use XHR but am getting an error when trying to post the form data.

First I call my function to download the PDF file.

```
const tempFile = await downloadPD(pandaDoc[doc].data.id);
```

```
async function downloadPD(docID) {
    const { data: tempFile } = await axios({
      url: `https://api.pandadoc.com/public/v1/documents/${docID}/download`,
      method: "GET",
      headers: {
        Authorization: `API-Key ${process.env.pandaDoc_KCSW_API_Key}`,
      },
      responseType: "arraybuffer",
    });

    return tempFile;
  }
```

I then call my function to upload to the destination platform, passing the necessary parameters.

```
const upldFile = await uploadPS(pandaDoc[doc].data.metadata.projectID,folderID,tempFile,fileName);
```

```
async function uploadPS(projectID, folderID, file, fileName) {
    let psDoc = new formData();
    psDoc.append("file", file);

    const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open(
      "POST",
      `${process.env.projSight_baseURL_v1_0}/${process.env.projSight_KCSW_prodPortfolio}/${projectID}/files/uploadFile?folderID=${folderID}`
    );
    xhr.withCredentials = true;
    xhr.setRequestHeader("x-api-key", process.env.projSight_KCSW_planPkgKey);
    xhr.setRequestHeader("authorization", `Bearer ${ps_token}`);
    xhr.send(psDoc);
  
    return upldDoc;
  }
```

My debugger returns the following error message:

> System.Private.CoreLib: Exception while executing function: Functions.PandaDoc_FileTransfer. System.Private.CoreLib: Result: Failure
> Exception: TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "string" argument must be of type string or an instance of Buffer or ArrayBuffer. Received an instance of FormData
> Stack: TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "string" argument must be of type string or an instance of Buffer or ArrayBuffer. Received an instance of FormData
> at new NodeError (internal/errors.js:322:7)
> at Function.byteLength (buffer.js:750:11)
> at exports.XMLHttpRequest.send (C:\VSCode\KCSW Functions\node_modules\xmlhttprequest\lib\XMLHttpRequest.js:363:80)
> at uploadPS (C:\VSCode\KCSW Functions\PandaDoc_FileTransfer\index.js:358:9)
> at module.exports (C:\VSCode\KCSW Functions\PandaDoc_FileTransfer\index.js:57:28)
> at runMicrotasks ()
> at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:95:5).

*at uploadPS (C:\VSCode\KCSW Functions\PandaDoc_FileTransfer\index.js:358:9)* is the line `xhr.send(psDoc)` in my 2nd function.

How can I take this tempFile and post it to the destination successfully?
If XHR is supposed to be able to handle form data, what am I missing in my code to make it happen?
Is there another option - something that can handle files larger than 10MB?

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use your function without `FormData` because if you use `node-XMLHttpRequest` lib then it doesn't support `FormData` https://github.com/driverdan/node-XMLHttpRequest/issues/174

```
async function uploadPS(projectID, folderID, file, fileName) {
    const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open(
      "POST",
      `${process.env.projSight_baseURL_v1_0}/${process.env.projSight_KCSW_prodPortfolio}/${projectID}/files/uploadFile?folderID=${folderID}`
    );
    xhr.withCredentials = true;
    xhr.setRequestHeader("x-api-key", process.env.projSight_KCSW_planPkgKey);
    xhr.setRequestHeader("authorization", `Bearer ${ps_token}`);
    xhr.send(file);
  
    return upldDoc;
  }
```

Also, I think you can return to `axios` with `maxBodyLength` param, eg

```
await axios({
        method: 'post',
        url: url,
        maxBodyLength: `Infinity`,
    }).catch(err => {
        throw err;
    })
```